# Spring Integration DSL Cafe example -- how are channels wired?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

The Spring DSL documentation provides a sample project -- [café](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/dsl/cafe-dsl/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/dsl/cafe/Application.java)

I'm unsure of a couple of aspects of how this works.  Pasting the relevant excerpts here:  (Full source at the above link)

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    Cafe cafe = ctx.getBean(Cafe.class);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        Order order = new Order(i);
        order.addItem(DrinkType.LATTE, 2, false);
        order.addItem(DrinkType.MOCHA, 3, true);
        cafe.placeOrder(order);
    }

    Thread.sleep(60000);

    ctx.close();
}

@MessagingGateway
public interface Cafe {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "orders.input")
    void placeOrder(Order order);

}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow orders() {
    return f -> f
            .split(Order.class, Order::getItems)
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            // SNIP
}
```

Reading this example, I'm unclear on a couple of points:

- The `Cafe` interface exposes a `@Gateway` that connects to `requestChannel = "orders.input"`.  However, this channnel is not defined anywhere.  How does this work?
- The DSL snippet does is not wired to consume from any channels, nor does it refer to the `Cafe::placeOrder` method -- how does this get connected to the `orders.input` channel to receive the inbound `Order`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just published (yesterday) a [line-by-line tutorial for the cafe dsl sample](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/25/spring-integration-java-dsl-line-by-line-tutorial) which goes into a lot of details about the internals.

When using the lambda version (`f -> f.split()...`) the framework declares an implicit `DirectChannel` with the bean name (`"orders"`) + `".input"` as its id.

You can also use `return IntegrationFlows.from("myChannel"). ... .get()` instead of the lambda expression and, again, the framework will auto-generate the channel if not declared as a bean already.

See the `InterationFlows` javadoc for more information.

`cafe.placeOrder()` is invoked in the last line in the for loop in the `main` method. The framework creates a proxy for the interface that wraps the `Order` object in a message and sends it to the gateway's request channel.

Comment: Ah, the implicit channel using the bean name was the piece I was missing.  FWIW, the docs could make this a bit clearer (though I appreciate the ink is hardly dry on this stuff). Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thanks, Gary! Marty, actually docs does that for you. See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#flows. If it still isn't clear, please, raise a GH-issue on the matter.